# Android JSON names order

Tags: java, android, json

I'm using the following code to parse info from a site and it works expect that the older in the last for loop goes out of whack. `names()` comes out as

`["569","570","565","566","567","568","562","563","564"]`

those number should be in numeric order but they aren't. Is there a good way to fix this?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.util.Log;

public class JSON {
   private String html;
   private String version = "version";
   private String pageString = null;
   private String urlString = "http://frc-manual.usfirst.org/a/GetAllItems/ManualID=3";

   public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;
   public JSON(String page){
      this.pageString = page;
   }
   public String getHTML(){
      return html;
   }
   public String getVersion(){
      return version;
   }

   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
   public void readAndParseJSON(String in) {
      try {
         JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(in);


         JSONObject head = reader.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("SubChapter").getJSONObject("3").getJSONObject("children").getJSONObject(pageString);
         html = head.getString("item_content_text");

         if(head.has("children")){
             JSONObject children = head.getJSONObject("children");
             JSONArray sub1 = new JSONArray(children.names().toString());
             for(int i=sub1.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
                 JSONObject children2 = children.getJSONObject(Integer.toString(sub1.getInt(i)));
                 html = html + "<h2>" + children2.getString("secdisp")+ " " + children2.getString("item_name") + "</h2>";
                 html = html + children2.getString("item_content_text");
                 if(children2.has("children")){
                     JSONObject children3 = children2.getJSONObject("children");
                     JSONArray sub2 = new JSONArray(children3.names().toString());
                     html = html + sub2;
                     for(int j=sub2.length()-1;j>=0;j--){
                         JSONObject children4 = children3.getJSONObject((String) sub2.get(j));
                         html = html + "<h3>" + children4.getString("secdisp")+ " " + children4.getString("item_name") + "</h3>";
                         html = html + children4.getString("item_content_text");
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

         JSONObject main  = reader.getJSONObject("data");
         version = main.getString("LatestManualUpdate");

         parsingComplete = false;



        } catch (Exception e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

   }
   public void fetchJSON(){
      Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
         @Override
         public void run() {
         try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
         InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

      String data = convertStreamToString(stream);

      readAndParseJSON(data);
         stream.close();

         } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         }
      });

       thread.start();      
   }
   static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
      java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
      return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of the keys in a `JSONObject` is undefined (see the documentation for [keys()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys%28%29)).  In practice, this means they will likely be ordered according to their hash codes, which is clearly not what you want.  If you need to keep these items in a specific order, you could either:

- Use a different JSON parser.  There are plenty available with a google search; I'd suggest that perhaps a "push-parser" may be the most appropriate type, as this will be guaranteed to give you the items in the object one after another in the order they are defined.  [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) is one such parser.  Look at their examples 5 & 6 in the "decoding examples" page.  Alternatively, see example 4 for how to change the type of `Map` it uses for storing JSON objects in its object-model mode, and note that a `LinkedHashMap` preserves the order the values are added to it.
- Sort the list of names before you use them
- Change the JSON to use an array of objects which contain the number rather than an object with the numbers as keys, as arrays are (obviously) kept in the order they appear in the original JSON.

Comment: None of the parsers I have found online worked well with this JSON code. I can't change the JSON because it isn't mine and is completely without arrays which has been giving me some problems. I shall look into sorting the lists.

Comment: See updated answer: I think a push-parser like json-simple would be the best solution; they're slightly harder to work with, but they do preserve ordering of elements unlike the kind that build an object model like `JSONObject`.

Comment: Also, looking at the documentation, json-simple can produce an object output with a similar API to Android's JSON parser, but you can control the type of the `Map` it uses to store the values: `LinkedHashMap` can be used to preserve the order the items are added.  This may be the simplest solution, as your code would not need to change very much to use this.

Comment: I did a small modification to JSON-Java that retains the sort order, if the input is an instance of SortedMap. See https://github.com/uklimaschewski/JSON-java/commit/835ec2cfcc00d72d0dc0ff3ff2bc6b3bd2c5293c it was rejected by Doug (as usual), see https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/pull/91

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting something that is outside the representational model for JSON.

According to the [JSON specification](http://json.org/):

> *"An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs."*

The fact that you can imply an order is not relevant.  The JSON information model does not recognize that such an ordering exists.  That is why *most* JSON parsers ignore your implied ordering, and many in-memory JSON object representations have no way of recording it.

---

So what should you do?

My recommendation would be to *change* your JSON schema.  For example, instead of this:

```
{ "name1" : "value1", "name2" : "value2", "name3" : "value3" }
```

write:

```
[ [ "name1", "value1" ], [ "name2", "value2" ], [ "name3", "value3" ] ]
```

or

```
[ { "name": "name1", "val" : "value1" }, 
  { "name": "name2", "val" : "value2" }, 
  { "name": "name3", "val" : "value3" } ]
```

... both of which are guaranteed to preserve the order of the entries.

---

It is also possible to "hack" a solution; i.e. there are ways to get some JSON parsers to preserve the order of name/value pairs that is implied by the serial form.  (I'm not going to explain how, because I think it is a really bad idea.)

The problem with doing this is that it ignores interoperability.  One of the most important reasons for using JSON (or XML, or any other standard format) is that people can use **any** spec-conformant software to generate and parse the "stuff" used for data interchange.  But what you are doing is *taking away* that advantage by adding extra requirements that directly contradict the JSON spec.

Comment: While I agree that a certain order must not be expected, from time to time, it is just a comfortable feature to have e.g. a debug switch on the server that will use a TreeMap instead of a Hashmap and respond this to the client, keeping the sort order. Having a Json mapper in between, that randomizes your debugging efforts can be a pain then.

Comment: I'm not convinced.  The order of the names in a hash is not random, and is likely to stay consistent if the input JSON is the same.